# Trying to get ID after /path/index.php?id - But not working

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to GET the ID of a `index.php`, I would like it to look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/path/<--ID goes here-->
```

I have tried to put this in my `.htaccess` file, but it wont work!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

And ofcourse I use `$ID = $_GET['id'];` to get the ID.

I would also like it to work, if a vistor types the following..

```
www.mysite.com/<--ID goes here-->
```

I know a code that works for the above, but it doesn't work for the other path.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Of course it isn't going to work if you redirect to `?uri=$1` but try to access the value using `$_GET['id']` -  "uri" and "id" don't match!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(path)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: For some reason it only works with mysite.com/ID and not mysite.com/path/ID. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in `/path/` directory?

Comment: I dont think that it gets the index.php from the path, because I disabled redirect in that php file, so for some reason it reads from the root index.php --- And no.

Comment: Thought it worked, but it still reads from the root index.php

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot to change the path name.. :D Thanks, marked as answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$ID = $_GET['uri']` since that's what you are adding in the RewriteRule